# Apache mod_proxy connection pooling with round-robin DNS backend

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

According to the [mod_proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html):

> DNS resolution happens when the socket to the origin domain is created for the first time. When connection pooling is used, each backend domain is resolved only once per child process, and reused for all further connections until the child is recycled. This information should to be considered while planning DNS maintenance tasks involving backend domains. Please also check ProxyPass parameters for more details about connection reuse.

When proxying an ELB backend, this becomes a problem. ELB nodes are under round-robin DNS. This means that Apache can end up forwarding requests to an ELB node that is no longer active.

One solution to this problem is to disable connection reuse with a proxy balancer that sets `disableReuse=On`. This forces Apache to open a new connection for every proxied request.

This breaks down once the number of requests exceeds around 500 per second. At this point connection pooling becomes crucial.

Is there a way to make use of proxy connection pooling whilst also re-resolving the DNS of a backend at some regular interval?

Is there a way to limit the number of requests that an Apache worker will process - thereby causing a new worker to spin up and re-resolve the DNS? I notice that `MaxRequestsPerChild` is now `MaxConnectionsPerChild`, which doesn't do the job given connections are persistent and long-lived.

My current solution is to schedule a regular graceful restart of Apache.